# How to let the user decide the number of appearing tables using JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcombobox

Im creating a ticket booking system for school, and i've got to a point where the user have to select the number of people from a JComboBox. The meaning with this combo box, is that for example the user chooses 3, then 3 boxes will appear, where the user shall type some contact information.

But every time i run my program, i have to set the numberOfPersons manually to getting it to work. I'm thinking of a way, that sets the selected value in the JComboBox equal to the numberOfPersons variable. But how? Any help is appreciated..

here is my code so far (btw, i have some other classes as well, but this should be enough i hope)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

/**
 * This class draws the panel in which you can fill in passengers data
 *
 * @author (mbom@itu.dk, moalb@itu.dk, vjba@itu.dk)
 */
public class PersonInfoDraw extends MakeReservationGUIDrawer
{

    private JFrame frame;
    ArrayList<JPanel> infoPanelArray;
    ArrayList<JTextField> textFieldArray;
    private String[] chosenNumberOfPersons =
    {
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
    };
    JComboBox dropDownPersons = new JComboBox(chosenNumberOfPersons);
    int numberOfPersons = 5;

    public PersonInfoDraw(MakeReservationGUIFlow parentObject, JPanel panel)
    {
        super(parentObject, panel);
        fillFrame(panel);
    }

    public void fillFrame(JPanel parentsPanel)
    {

        frame = new JFrame();
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Indtast Kundeinformation: ");
        titleLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        northPanel.add(titleLabel);
        northPanel.add(dropDownPersons);
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        final JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(((int) Math.ceil((numberOfPersons / 2.0))), 1));

        contentPane.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        centerPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
        centerPanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());

        /* infoPanelArray holder et array af JPanels. Hvis der er 3 passagerer
         vil infoPanelArray tilsidst indeholde 3 JPanels */
        infoPanelArray = new ArrayList<>();

        /*
         textFieldArray holder et array af tekstfelter. Det gør at vi senere let
         kan tilgå indholdet af tekstfelterne
         */
        textFieldArray = new ArrayList<>();

        /* Et array af string-beskrivelser til de JLabels, der placeres ved 
         siden af tekstfelterne i GUI'et
         */


        int counter = 0;
        int x;
        /* Denne løkke køres lige så mange gange, som det valgte antal 
         passagerer
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPersons; i++)
        {
            /* 
             Først tilføjes et JPanel(5 rækker, 2 kolonner) til infoPanelArray.
             Bemærk, at et JPanel med GridLayout fyldes ud rækkevist, 
             ikke kolonnevist!
             */
            infoPanelArray.add(new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, numberOfPersons)));

            x = i + 1;
            String[] descriptions =
            {
                "  Fornavn: (Person " + x + ")*", "  Efternavn:*", "  CPR-nummer:*", "  Pasnummer:*",
            };

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                /* I det JPanel, som vi lige har lagt ind i infoPanelArray
                 tilføjes nu en JLabel med en string fra descriptions-arrayet
                 */
                infoPanelArray.get(i).add(new JLabel(descriptions[j]));

                /*
                 Herefter tilføjes et JTextField
                 */
                textFieldArray.add(new JTextField(15));

                /*
                 Nu tilføjes det JTextField, vi lige har lavet, til infoPanel
                 */
                infoPanelArray.get(i).add(textFieldArray.get(counter));

                counter++;

            }

            // Til sidst lægges det ind i centerPanel
            centerPanel.add(infoPanelArray.get(i));
        }

        JButton button = new JButton("Gem og fortsæt");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                revealNextStep();
            }

        });

        southPanel.add(button);

        frame.pack();
        contentPane.setVisible(true);

        parentsPanel.add(contentPane);
        parentsPanel.updateUI();
    }

    protected void revealNextStep()
    {
        parentObject.drawSeatSelector();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an Integer array for numerical values

```
Integer[] chosenNumberOfPersons = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
JComboBox dropDownPersons = new JComboBox(chosenNumberOfPersons);
int numberOfPersons = 0;

...

dropDownPersons.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
        numberOfPersons = (Integer)dropDownPersons.getSelectedItem();
    }
});
```

---

Or the way you have it with a String[], just parse it

```
dropDownPersons.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
        numberOfPersons = Integer.parseInt(dropDownPersons.getSelectedItem());
    }
});
```

Comment: When i try the things you suggest above, the program compiles, but nothing happens when i select on of the numbers in the JComboBox. The number selected in the combo box, should be the number of tables to appear on the screen.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you code is supposed to work, without actually testing fully runnable code. I can only guess (if the panel is drawing something) you may want to add `repaint();` at the end of the method.